# out of memory on every other run, on Android

Tags: android, memory

my app runs fine the first run, but if i restart it crashes and makes me force close. after i hit the force close button then i can start the app again. if i then try to restart after hitting the back button i have to force close. i lets me run it without error every other attempt. i thought android was supposed to take care of returning memory to the computer so we dont have to do that housekeeping: i do have a somewhat large array:

```
int  worldgrid= new int[640][480][3];
```

in my constructor, i may have to shorten it. i does work the first attempt though. log cat messages:

> 05-08 19:09:46.035: E/dalvikvm-heap(420): Out of memory on a 28-byte
>   allocation.
>
> 05-08 19:09:46.195: I/dalvikvm(420):   | group="main" sCount=0
>   dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4001d8e0 self=0xccb0 05-08 19:09:46.195:
>   I/dalvikvm(420):   | sysTid=420 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default
>   handle=-1345026008 05-08 19:09:46.205: I/dalvikvm(420):   |
>   schedstat=( 52616400652 22917249866 1196 ) 05-08 19:09:46.205:
>   I/dalvikvm(420):   at java.lang.reflect.Array.createMultiArray(Native
>   Method) 05-08 19:09:46.205: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:444) 05-08
>   19:09:46.455: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   com.gravedigger.MainGamePanel.(MainGamePanel.java:215) 05-08
>   19:09:46.455: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   com.digger.DiggerActivity.onCreate(GravediggerActivity.java:116) 05-08
>   19:09:46.615: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   05-08 19:09:46.625: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
>   05-08 19:09:46.765: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   05-08 19:09:46.765: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) 05-08
>   19:09:46.775: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   05-08 19:09:46.775: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 05-08
>   19:09:46.785: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 05-08 19:09:46.785:
>   I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 05-08
>   19:09:46.895: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 05-08
>   19:09:46.895: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 05-08 19:09:46.895:
>   I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   05-08 19:09:46.895: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 05-08
>   19:09:46.905: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 05-08 19:09:47.038:
>   E/dalvikvm(420): HeapWorker is wedged: 11152ms spent inside
>   Lcom/android/internal/os/BinderInternal$GcWatcher;.finalize()V 05-08
>   19:09:47.038: I/dalvikvm(420): DALVIK THREADS: 05-08 19:09:47.045:
>   I/dalvikvm(420): "main" prio=5 tid=1 VMWAIT
>
> 05-08 19:09:47.045: I/dalvikvm(420):   | group="main" sCount=1
>   dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4001d8e0 self=0xccb0 05-08 19:09:47.045:
>   I/dalvikvm(420):   | sysTid=420 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default
>   handle=-1345026008 05-08 19:09:47.045: I/dalvikvm(420):   |
>   schedstat=( 52980087202 23270903160 1219 ) 05-08 19:09:47.045:
>   I/dalvikvm(420):   at java.lang.reflect.Array.createMultiArray(Native
>   Method) 05-08 19:09:47.045: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:444) 05-08
>   19:09:47.045: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   com.digger.MainGamePanel.(MainGamePanel.java:215) 05-08
>   19:09:47.045: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   com.digger.DiggerActivity.onCreate(GravediggerActivity.java:116) 05-08
>   19:09:47.045: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   05-08 19:09:47.185: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
>   05-08 19:09:47.185: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   05-08 19:09:47.195: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) 05-08
>   19:09:47.195: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   05-08 19:09:47.195: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 05-08
>   19:09:47.195: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 05-08 19:09:47.195:
>   I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 05-08
>   19:09:47.195: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 05-08
>   19:09:47.195: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 05-08 19:09:47.195:
>   I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   05-08 19:09:47.195: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 05-08
>   19:09:47.195: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 05-08 19:09:47.195:
>   I/dalvikvm(420): "Binder Thread #2" prio=5 tid=6 NATIVE 05-08
>   19:09:47.195: I/dalvikvm(420):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N
>   obj=0x44f366b8 self=0x11d230 05-08 19:09:47.195: I/dalvikvm(420):   |
>   sysTid=425 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1297528 05-08
>   19:09:47.195: I/dalvikvm(420):   | schedstat=( 118912719 416670422 51
>   ) 05-08 19:09:47.195: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method) 05-08 19:09:47.195:
>   I/dalvikvm(420): "Binder Thread #1" prio=5 tid=5 NATIVE 05-08
>   19:09:47.195: I/dalvikvm(420):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N
>   obj=0x44f36480 self=0x11fd80 05-08 19:09:47.750: I/dalvikvm(420):   |
>   sysTid=424 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1269616 05-08
>   19:09:47.750: I/dalvikvm(420):   | schedstat=( 114332827 305656917 35
>   ) 05-08 19:09:47.750: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method) 05-08 19:09:47.755:
>   I/dalvikvm(420): "JDWP" daemon prio=5 tid=4 VMWAIT 05-08 19:09:47.755:
>   I/dalvikvm(420):   | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N
>   obj=0x44f352a0 self=0x135ad0 05-08 19:09:47.755: I/dalvikvm(420):   |
>   sysTid=423 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1196352 05-08
>   19:09:47.765: I/dalvikvm(420):   | schedstat=( 59551849 158373474 18 )
>   05-08 19:09:47.765: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method) 05-08 19:09:47.775:
>   I/dalvikvm(420): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=3 VMWAIT 05-08
>   19:09:47.886: I/dalvikvm(420):   | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0
>   s=N obj=0x44f351e8 self=0x125550 05-08 19:09:47.886: I/dalvikvm(420): 
>   | sysTid=422 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1240608 05-08
>   19:09:47.886: I/dalvikvm(420):   | schedstat=( 2639901 40055709 3 )
>   05-08 19:09:47.886: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method) 05-08 19:09:47.886:
>   I/dalvikvm(420): "HeapWorker" daemon prio=5 tid=2 RUNNABLE 05-08
>   19:09:47.886: I/dalvikvm(420):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0
>   s=N obj=0x438b8e50 self=0x12ece0 05-08 19:09:47.886: I/dalvikvm(420): 
>   | sysTid=421 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1195896 05-08
>   19:09:47.906: I/dalvikvm(420):   | schedstat=( 4477669539 2785983510
>   211 ) 05-08 19:09:47.906: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher.finalize(BinderInternal.java:~48)
>   05-08 19:09:47.906: I/dalvikvm(420):   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method) 05-08 19:09:47.906:
>   D/dalvikvm(420): threadid=2: sending two SIGSTKFLTs to threadid=2
>   (tid=421) to cause debuggerd dump 05-08 19:09:57.895: D/dalvikvm(420):
>   Sent, pausing to let debuggerd run 05-08 19:10:05.956:
>   D/dalvikvm(420): Continuing 05-08 19:10:05.956: E/dalvikvm(420): VM
>   aborting

Answer (score 1):

Probably, not good to have so pretty big arrays in memory.
But anyway, you can decrease memory usage by refactoring your array this way:
int  worldgrid = new int[3][480][640];

This trick will reduce memory usage in several times. It's related with java memory overhead for arrays and each item, details can be found here.
http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/array_memory_usage.shtml

Also check, that you don't keep any link to array, it will prevent removing it from memory. Also garbage collector doesn't remove from memory right after removing all links. So, if you don't make link to array equal to null, it's kept in memory and when you restart your app (there is no guaranty that activity was killed fully), and try to create array in onCreate (as I see from log) the old array can be not yet removed.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why you are getting the error every other time without seeing the rest of your code. Do you have static variables you are using?

However I can give you advice on lessening your memory consumption by a factor of 3. It looks like you are attempting to store an rgb image. The problem is each red, green, or blue pixel only needs one byte, but you are giving it an int which is 4 bytes. A better approach is to encode the red, green, and blue into a single int using: `int color = Color.rgb(red, geen, blue)`That way you only need to initialize your array to `int[]  worldgrid= new int[640][480]` and you cut down the memory usage by a factor of 3.

In addition, you should probably not even store it as a multi-dimensional array at all, and just do `int[] worldgrid = new int[640*480];`and when indexing into array, just do: `int result = worldgrid[row + col*640];`